# iphone app crashes on launch

Tags: iphone

I'm making my app in distribution to submit it at app store but I don't know whats going wrong. I didn't change the code, the app works fine in debug mode and every functionality is working well.

But, when I make adhoc distribution the app doesn't load at all just shows the splash screen for a long time and then crashes. I checked the device logs but I was unable to understand what is the cause of it.

Can anyone help me with it? I'm stuck here and need to launch my app quickly. I'm using SDK 4.3 ,iOS 4.3.1 and XCode 3.2.6

```
Incident Identifier: A66AB4EB-0B4B-404C-B29D-3B9AFD327D27
CrashReporter Key:   424521b1d24eeb29c9e951546ee35fad4f1f2a6a
Hardware Model:      iPod3,1
Process:         MouseWait [897]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1BF3647F-710B-42F0-A9F7-E190C6C8902E/MouseWait.app/MouseWait
Identifier:      MouseWait
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-31 19:17:25.143 +0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c8a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d333b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d2bbf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31a05a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3332d06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31a03e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31a03e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31a03f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3332bc84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x307e048a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
10  Foundation                      0x30a5256c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 56
11  UIKit                           0x31eb2a82 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 666
12  UIKit                           0x31eb2764 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 28
13  UIKit                           0x31eab0c6 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 930
14  UIKit                           0x31eaa276 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 134
15  UIKit                           0x31e565f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 20
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3074defc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
17  QuartzCore                      0x32dfabae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 114
18  QuartzCore                      0x32dfa966 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 178
19  QuartzCore                      0x32e001be CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 206
20  QuartzCore                      0x32dfffd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
21  QuartzCore                      0x32e0bdf8 CA::Transaction::flush() + 40
22  QuartzCore                      0x32e0bdc6 +[CATransaction flush] + 22
23  UIKit                           0x31e9591c -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 24
24  UIKit                           0x31e80c1c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 456
25  UIKit                           0x31e557d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
26  UIKit                           0x31e5520e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
27  UIKit                           0x31e54c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
28  GraphicsServices                0x33a86e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
29  CoreFoundation                  0x307b7a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
30  CoreFoundation                  0x307b9838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
31  CoreFoundation                  0x307ba606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3074aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
33  CoreFoundation                  0x3074adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
34  UIKit                           0x31e7fd42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
35  UIKit                           0x31e7d800 UIApplicationMain + 664
36  MouseWait                       0x00003002 main (main.m:12)
37  MouseWait                       0x00002f98 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c93ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d346d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c9fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3293e094 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 672
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3293f04a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3293e60a _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 190
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3458a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c93ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d346d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6c5c semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6f52 semaphore_wait_signal + 2
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d31734 pthread_mutex_lock + 256
3   WebCore                         0x30b77402 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 150
4   WebCore                         0x30b77342 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 14
5   CoreFoundation                  0x307b7a2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
6   CoreFoundation                  0x307b945e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
7   CoreFoundation                  0x307ba760 __CFRunLoopRun + 860
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3074aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3074adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
10  WebCore                         0x30b77292 RunWebThread(void*) + 382
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3330a _pthread_start + 242
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307b82b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307ba562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3074aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3074adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   CFNetwork                       0x33bd3a18 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 244
7   Foundation                      0x30aaba10 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 76
8   Foundation                      0x30a4dd5a -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 222
9   Foundation                      0x30a4d95a +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 34
10  MouseWait                       0x0000c8f4 -[CXMLDocument initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] (CXMLDocument.m:111)
11  MouseWait                       0x000131be +[CheckBan CheckBanStatus] (CheckBan.m:24)
12  MouseWait                       0x00003748 -[MouseWaitAppDelegate checkBanThread] (MouseWaitAppDelegate.m:197)
13  Foundation                      0x30a19382 -[NSThread main] + 38
14  Foundation                      0x30a8b5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3330a _pthread_start + 242
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c6758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307b82b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307ba562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3074aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3074adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x30a267f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x30a19382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x30a8b5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3330a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c93ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d346d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c8c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x307bd8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3330a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x309c8d18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d024ac nanosleep + 132
2   Foundation                      0x30a8c022 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 90
3   MouseWait                       0x00005ad8 -[DashboardViewController GetParkTimes] (DashboardViewController.m:256)
4   Foundation                      0x30a19382 -[NSThread main] + 38
5   Foundation                      0x30a8b5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d3330a _pthread_start + 242
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d34bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f52148c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0029099c      r7: 0x2fdfce94
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00287050     r11: 0x3f17c6fc
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfce88      lr: 0x347c03bb      pc: 0x31455a1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xc2fff +MouseWait armv6  <2adc81ca78b53b63a1d038a1147872d5> /var/mobile/Applications/1BF3647F-710B-42F0-A9F7-E190C6C8902E/MouseWait.app/MouseWait
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30aac000 - 0x30ac1fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30ac6000 - 0x30bd8fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <06a9ea3064dd3ecf87121d6678cc1e32> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x30d1b000 - 0x30d1bfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30d20000 - 0x30d23fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30d3f000 - 0x30d46fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30d63000 - 0x30eaffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <7b1ac06abad33dca99a29629b667f929> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30ec9000 - 0x30efcfff  iCalendar armv7  <e52c54abaab734e8b0278f358217c4b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30efd000 - 0x30f39fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30fa9000 - 0x31096fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x311cf000 - 0x312b4fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x312c5000 - 0x312d4fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <f258d39dc7d93faa9c9ff5cf81c5dcbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x31344000 - 0x31345fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31348000 - 0x3134dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3134e000 - 0x313fffff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31400000 - 0x31433fff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x31434000 - 0x31441fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31444000 - 0x3145bfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3145c000 - 0x3147cfff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x31489000 - 0x315a8fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x315a9000 - 0x315cdfff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x315ce000 - 0x315d0fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x315d1000 - 0x315d2fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x315fe000 - 0x31c09fff  WebCore armv7  <b25d7d87ebd235ecbceca611a063c73b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31c0a000 - 0x31c58fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x31c59000 - 0x31d1ffff  MusicLibrary armv7  <88f8b1070fbf3cbc80471a432ea1fafb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x31d93000 - 0x31e9bfff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31ebd000 - 0x321a4fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x321e2000 - 0x32237fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32256000 - 0x3228afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <aec2e22a2055380e82d4d0279faad0a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3228b000 - 0x322aafff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x322ab000 - 0x3232ffff  AVFoundation armv7  <9d5e43475961327384d6218d14de8b1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x32331000 - 0x32344fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x32347000 - 0x32347fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3234b000 - 0x32351fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3244e000 - 0x32498fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32540000 - 0x32587fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3259b000 - 0x325a6fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x325c3000 - 0x325c8fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x325c9000 - 0x325cbfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x325df000 - 0x32612fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32613000 - 0x32616fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x32617000 - 0x3261afff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3261b000 - 0x3261cfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3261d000 - 0x3267bfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32723000 - 0x32723fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32726000 - 0x32730fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3284c000 - 0x328d6fff  Message armv7  <1e4680ca7d4936bf9f575269b67e4402> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x328d7000 - 0x328d7fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x328de000 - 0x32c6bfff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32c88000 - 0x32cb6fff  MIME armv7  <28e35d5e19893de6bc28463efec5222f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x32cb7000 - 0x32d10fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x32d39000 - 0x32dcefff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32dcf000 - 0x32dd2fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32e5d000 - 0x32e76fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32e77000 - 0x32e97fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x32ed0000 - 0x32eedfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x32f0a000 - 0x32f47fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32f58000 - 0x32f90fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32f98000 - 0x32fa1fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32fa2000 - 0x32fa8fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x330d8000 - 0x3322cfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3322d000 - 0x33331fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33371000 - 0x333b7fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <4319daea186b3a22b148ca78000f11ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x333b8000 - 0x333c0fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x333c5000 - 0x333d2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x333d3000 - 0x333e3fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x337a7000 - 0x337b5fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3386b000 - 0x33871fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x33885000 - 0x33934fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33937000 - 0x3397afff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <01a5c5442e173624bdbde3c1f4ad4665> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3397b000 - 0x3397bfff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3397c000 - 0x339b3fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x339c8000 - 0x339f1fff  ContentIndex armv7  <f5a3613ec5b6392995d7ed0742f7419f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x33a8b000 - 0x33d9efff  GeoServices armv7  <8bbb5da6471a3e0d83a55a32c4d1fa9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x33db4000 - 0x33e78fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33e79000 - 0x33e7cfff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x33e7d000 - 0x33eb0fff  StoreServices armv7  <a74659288dea34bca7a7911c19cf2c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33eb1000 - 0x33ef1fff  CoreMedia armv7  <0fcb3d1136d033d3acd97519c4be3ac3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33f14000 - 0x33f3dfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33f3e000 - 0x33f42fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33f43000 - 0x33f44fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x33fd5000 - 0x33fdafff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3409d000 - 0x340eefff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x340f7000 - 0x34117fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3411e000 - 0x341c7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3425e000 - 0x342acfff  CoreMotion armv7  <8660c1394c5c39089407c07fd7fd8b52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x342f7000 - 0x3432cfff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34345000 - 0x3434cfff  WebUI armv7  <74070ad76277301fba6d3a5eb5f214b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x34350000 - 0x34388fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34389000 - 0x343b7fff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x344c5000 - 0x34504fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x34505000 - 0x3450efff  ITSync armv7  <dc57c003aad83864827ccf95fc579563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3450f000 - 0x3451bfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c508734deb43352782433a290ff235bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34573000 - 0x34576fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34596000 - 0x345a2fff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x345f4000 - 0x345f8fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x345f9000 - 0x346b8fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x346d8000 - 0x346dbfff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x346dc000 - 0x3471efff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3477f000 - 0x3478bfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3478d000 - 0x3480efff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3480f000 - 0x3483efff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3483f000 - 0x34840fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34847000 - 0x3484cfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x348cf000 - 0x3498bfff  MapKit armv7  <c212dc96889b3b57a03744eb12616768> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x3499a000 - 0x3499cfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3499d000 - 0x349a1fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34a25000 - 0x34a32fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <d454cde062983860a41694922eb5c042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x34a53000 - 0x34a55fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c0617d2a41283cc2bff1a1d770c06f8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34a70000 - 0x34a75fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x34a8a000 - 0x34a99fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x34b98000 - 0x34baafff  PersistentConnection armv7  <8de1cf029f8132a2946ccca351dbd4fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34d1b000 - 0x34d31fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9776dd6c96b531e9885bddacd2a8adb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34d42000 - 0x34d52fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34d56000 - 0x34d5ffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34d60000 - 0x34d61fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36a3d000 - 0x36aacfff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36aad000 - 0x36ab0fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36ac3000 - 0x36b60fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36b61000 - 0x36b63fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x36bdc000 - 0x36be3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x36d28000 - 0x36dcefff  Celestial armv7  <6a54406a081a3b5fa6b22754b013b629> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36dcf000 - 0x36dd1fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36dd9000 - 0x36efafff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36efb000 - 0x36f43fff  CoreLocation armv7  <90a87c2cdf823e6892aff81a6dde3430> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36fdb000 - 0x370f5fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37101000 - 0x37108fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x371f1000 - 0x371fffff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <e54fa5bf6f9333618401cdbaf665f227> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore


----------
```

Comment: There should be details written to the console about the NSException please include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this crash might be due to "app is launching WAYYYY TOO LOOOOONG". Check if your app is not doing any main-thread-resource-fetching (as I see it's launching with some url and payload). Also there might be some recursion in the way.

Also your code might use some configuration-pendent preprocessor macros which provide different code depending on whether they are defined or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply Eimantas,but I'm really struck I have searched many forums and gone through some of the answers all of them says that appDelegate's didFinishLaunching method is taking much more time in loading,but I have all code is to be run in separate threads because I'm working most of my work from network,I didn't understand why it is doing that it runs perfect in debug mode.

Comment: before this my app was working fine I have made made distribution adhocs but suddenly it starts crashing did it have to do something with my first viewControllerclass which I'm loading?